# public variable

Tags: c++, qt, variables, public

I want to make a variable that can be accessed by all classes that I have made. How do I do this? I have tried by stating in the mainwindow header file:

```
public:
    extern int number;
```

And then referencing to this in other classes by saying:

```
MainWindow::number;
```

This gives me an error: error: storage class specified for 'number'. Can anybody say what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: You should need the 'extern' keyword; delete it and it should work.

Comment: I have got a new error now: error: undefined reference to `MainWindow::numbers'. I thought I defined it in my mainwindow header file?

Comment: @TomPanning I think you forgot the word "not". Can you edit your comment?

Comment: @Frank you did not define it, you declared it. Defining it would be a line like `int MainWindow::number;` in the cpp file.

Comment: I think you confused 'extern' with 'static'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyword to success is `static`. Make it a static variable.

Comment: This, plus the comment of @qdii helped me solve the problem! Thanks!